# How to retry a loop iteration based on time limit or server error response?

Tags: r

I running the following for loop in order to get some information from a server. The loop iterates through a list of days `DimDate` and makes a GET request from a server.
this is the code im using so far. every day will be stored in df and then appended to df.master at the end.

```
df.master = data.frame()
df = data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(DimDate)){
  message(i)
  df = fromJSON(paste0(url1,"/",function, "/", id, "/", token1, "/", DimDate[i] ))
  df.master <- bind_rows(df.master, df)
}
```

my issue is that sometimes the server will hang (it will get stuck in a specific `i` and later return a response message. particularly 400-500-503. This kills the loop.

```
iteration 232
iteration 233
iteration 234
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Can you please advise on a improvement to my loop code so in case the loop gets stuck on a specific `i` for x minutes OR an error is returned, the loop will retry `i` for a couple times before either stopping (if too many retries) or jump to the next `i` (if server returns correct data and no error)

EDIT1:
My progress so far

```
max_retries <- 3
for (i in 1:length(DimDate)){
  message(paste("current:", i))
  retries <- 0L
  OK <- FALSE
  while(!OK){
    df <- tryCatch( expr = { fromJSON(paste0(url1,"/",
                                   funcion,"/",
                                   nit,"/",
                                   token1,"/",
                                   DimDate[i] ))},
                   error = function(e) { e } )
    if(inherits(df, "error")){
      if(retries < max_retries){
        Sys.sleep(1)
        retries <- retries + 1L
        message(paste("   Retry:", retries))
      } else break
    } else {OK <- TRUE}
  }
  if(OK) {
    df.master <- bind_rows(df.master, df)
    cat("Dim 'df.master':", dim(df.master), "\n")
    }
}
```

as a test, im passing a corrupt function with the GET so i can get a error back from the server. The code tries 3 times on the current iteration, **doesnt stop but jumps to the following iteration**

```
current: 1
   Retry: 1
   Retry: 2
   Retry: 3
current: 2
   Retry: 1
   Retry: 2
   Retry: 3
current: 3
   Retry: 1
   Retry: 2
   Retry: 3
current: 4
   Retry: 1
   Retry: 2
>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question's problem seems to be asking for a loop calling `tryCatch` and `Sys.sleep` a maximum number of times whenever an error occurs.
Maybe something like the following.

```
df.master <- NULL
max_retries <- 2

for (i in 1:length(DimDate)){
  message(paste("Current:", i))
  retries <- 0L
  OK <- FALSE
  while(!OK){
    df <- tryCatch(fromJSON(paste0(url1,"/", Function, "/", id, "/", token1, "/", DimDate[i] )),
                   error = function(e) e)
    if(inherits(df, "error")){
      message(df$message)
      if(retries < max_retries){
        Sys.sleep(1)
        retries <- retries + 1L
        message(paste("   Retry:", retries))
      } else break
    } else OK <- TRUE
  }
  if(OK) {
    df.master <- bind_rows(df.master, df)
    cat("Dim 'df.master':", dim(df.master), "\n")
  }
}
```

---

If instead of a loop, the code is rewritten as a function returning the data.frame of what could be read with GET and the errors, then, later, those that gave errors could be tried again. The function below has an extra argument, `wait`, the time in seconds to wait before retrying with default 1.

```
retry_fromJSON <- function(DDate, URL, max_retries = 3, wait = 1, verbose = TRUE){
  out <- lapply(seq_along(DDate), function(i){
    if(verbose){
      message(paste("Current:", i))
    }
    current_URL <- paste(URL, DDate[i], sep = "/")
    retries <- 0L
    OK <- FALSE
    while(!OK){
      df <- tryCatch(fromJSON(current_URL), error = function(e) e)
      if(inherits(df, "error")){
        if(verbose){
          message(df$message)
        }
        if(retries < max_retries){
          Sys.sleep(time = wait)
          retries <- retries + 1L
          if(verbose){
            message(paste("   Retry:", retries))
          }
        } else break
      } else {OK <- TRUE}
    }
    if(OK) {
      if(verbose){
        msg <- paste("Read df with dim:", dim(df))
        message(msg)
      }
    }
    df
  })
  err <- sapply(out, inherits, "error")
  df.master <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, out[!err])
  errors <- sapply(out[err], "[[", "message")
  list(df.master = df.master, which.err = which(err), errors = errors)
}

url2 <- paste(url1, funcion, id, token1, sep = "/")
result <- retry_fromJSON(DimDate, url2)
result$df.master    # the data.frame
result$errors       # the error messages
result$which.err    # DimDate indices that threw error
```

Now a second pass can be made.

```
NewDimDate <- DimDate[result$which.err]
result <- retry_fromJSON(NewDimDate, url2)
```

Comment: i dont think this is catching the error as i tries twice each iteration but jumps to the next one

Comment: @AndresMora It tries twice even when it can read in the data? Can ypu put a `print(dim(df.master))` after the `if(OK)` instruction?

Comment: @AndresMora So it only tries 2 times and then continues to the next one? Increase the `max_retries <- 3`. Try the code edited, it might make the messages more clear. And in your edit to the question, you `print(e)`, don't do that, let it return `e`, assign to df and print after. See mine, it uses `message(df$message)`.

Comment: No luck so far. Code does the 3 times on iteration 1 and keeps going. please see updated question

Comment: shouldnt `if(inherits(df, "error"))` have a "equal" condition?

Comment: @AndresMora No, it shouldn't. It already is `FALSE/TRUE`. After reading the question, I am not understanding if you want the code to stop iterating through `DimDate`. It should only go until the end if *all* files are read?

Comment: the code nees to iterate through DimDate but to retry every iteration x number of times **in case an error comes from server**. if the error keeps coming after x retries, then stop. otherwise continue to the next iteration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231675/discussion-between-rui-barradas-and-andres-mora).